# C++ Lua Error Handling

Tags: c++, error-handling, lua

I am working on a program (C++, with D3D9) and Lua. I already implemented the LUA Api and everything is working fine, beside the error handling. I googled alot and I found a solution that handles most of the errors. I write this because of the other errors.

I will show you some relevant code in pictures.

[image: Code Part 1 (LUA)]

[image: Code Part 2 (LUA)]

[image: Part 3 (Console Output)]

Now the most important functions: PerformCall() and LuaErrorReport()

[image: Part 4 (C++)]
[image: Part 5 (PerformCall)]

However, as I said before: Some errors are being handled. But this one is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts on what could be wrong. You're passing `L`  for `lua_pcall` while `LuaErrorReport` gets `State()` instead. They could be working on different `lua_State` which can happen like in the context of a coroutine. If this is intentional, at the very least indicate somewhere why this is being done.

The `lua_pushvalue` inside `LuaErrorReport` also looks suspicious. How do you know the bottom value on the stack holds the message you're reporting? This function gets called from other functions that may have accumulated more values on the stack. I would either change that to

```
lua_pushvalue(L, -3);
```

or

```
lua_pushstring(L, msg);
```

Lastly, you should also considering passing `debug.traceback` as the error function to `lua_pcall` to get a more meaningful stacktrace error message. Something like:

```
void LUA::PerformCall(int return_amount)
{
  lua_getglobal(L, "debug");
  lua_getfield(L, -1, "traceback");
  lua_remove(L, -2);
  int errindex = -p_iArgCount - 2;
  lua_insert(L, errindex);
  int error = lua_pcall(L, p_iArgCount, return_amount, errindex);
  // ...
```

And get rid of the `debug.trace` call in `LuaErrorReport`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. All the Code is in the Class LUA that has a private member lua_State* L. It also has the public Function lua_State* State() that returns L. I dont think that causes the error. I will try the rest tomorrow.

Comment: I tested out the code and everything is working now. Thanks alot.

Comment: I have another question. Once an error is handled by the Error Handling Function, the error keeps happening (its spamming the console). Any way to stop this?

Comment: @Freakyy how does `PerformCall` get used by other code? Does "PerformCall" expect calling code to setup the stack in someway prior to call? What about after the call complete?

Comment: PerformCall gets called each D3D9-BeginScene to call the render function. But the function causing the error gets called only once.

Comment: What you can do to track down the bug is whenever `PerformCall` is executed, if the `pcall` is an error print out what the lua stack contains prior to call. This will help narrow down if the repeated error is due to executing the same lua chunk repeatedly or something else.

Comment: I dumped the stack after the LuaErrorReport was called and an error is to be raised. The result: 2 in Stack (1 Function + 1 String = Error String) - And the same thing right after the Error was printed (Same result, 2 in Stack) **Nevermind! Fixed it!** Thank you for your help, it didn't work because in the LuaErrorReport Function a lua call to a LuaErrorFunction (in the lua code) was made. It works now!